# Idea for cold cellar

Tags: shed

I will be building a shed attached to my house garage. It will have an insulated monolithic pour concrete foundation.
I want to incorporate somewhat of a small cold cellar in the foundation. How do I go about that in the best way?

Comment: Seems that your just describing a partial basement under the shed. I've found that preliminary sketches steer me into good final drawings. If its a small shed, a full basement may be the most practical plan. The design would hinge some on where the cellar access is placed (inside or outside the shed).

Answer (score 1):

A shed it’s a mono pour is 1/2 of what you need. I have built cold rooms using simple Window AC units by modifying the sensors and adding several inches of insulation on each wall and the roof a shed cans be turned into a cool room even a light freezer

My largest one was in my last place and that one did hold and cool up to 3 elk. My current one is less than 1/2 the size but has a larger compressor and coil set to freeze in some shelves to freeze the meat after processing, but is still “ temporary. 
Next season I will put up the inside 2 walls and ceiling and turn on the compressor again.

My first unit I think I used a 12kbtu window system and it was great but I no longer live there. I did use a kit to modify the ac unit even though I could have built up what I have now it was much cheaper and I had a window unit that worked.

I would look up cool rooms with window ac units or kits to turn a window unit into a cooler (it has been many years) but is legal because the electronics are all that are modified and it works.